# Is the default constructor called differently when using parentheses versus nothing? (on a template class struct)

Tags: c++, templates, struct, constructor, most-vexing-parse

I've been writing some code for a project that includes OpenGL, and I've discovered weird behavior with my vec4 struct, of which I could not find an explanation.

Here's the relevant snippet of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct vec4 {
    T data[4];
    vec4(T v1 = (T) 0, T v2 = (T) 0, T v3 = (T) 0, T v4 = (T) 1) {
        data[0] = v1;
        data[1] = v2;
        data[2] = v3;
        data[3] = v4;

    }
    void print() {
        cout << "[ " << data[0] << ", " << data[1] << ", " << data[2] << ", " << data[3] << " ]" << endl;

    }
};
int main() {
    vec4<int> test1;     //Instantiating like this is fine
    test1.print();

    vec4<int> test2();   //Instantiating like this leads to errors
    test2.print();

    vec4<int> test3(0);  //Instantiating like this is also fine
    test3.print();

    // ...

    return 0;

}
```

As you can see, the only difference is using parentheses or not. When I use the parentheses, I get various errors such as:

`main.cpp:222:11: error: request for member 'print' in 'test2', which is of non-class type 'vec4<int>()'`

`main.cpp:226:18: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'matrix<int>' and 'vec4<int>()')`

I get none of these errors if I exclude the parentheses. (I should note that there is an operator overload function defined, but excluded from my snippet. It works with `matrix<int>` and `vec4<int>`.)

Does anyone have an explanation to this behavior? Are there any situations where such behavior could lead to problems?

Thank you!

Comment: Most vexing parse.

Comment: It can be a good idea to run code through Clang if you can't figure out something GCC gives you. Clang gives a [really nice warning](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/H_Ydxg) here.

Comment: You're right, it looks like it is interpreted as a function declaration. Thanks chris!

Comment: I want to note that this was a well asked question, it just happens to have been asked before. +1 from me.

Comment: Thank you, jxh! Sometimes it would seem no matter how much you search, you just can't search the right question sometimes. Despite it being an accidental duplicate, I still learned what I hoped to, so I appreciate the help!